# Does anyone know if it's possible to display the assistant in both the assistant field and the direct reports list for a manager (org chart)?

Tags: user-profile, my-site, social

Does anyone know if it's possible to display the assistant in both the assistant field and the direct reports list for a manager (in the Organizational Browser chart).

Manager-A has three direct reportees, if he adds a reportee as his assistant then that reportee is got removed from the direct reportee list  (in the Organizational Browser chart).

Is that an expected behavior or a bug in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

The Organizational Browser chart bases it's hierarchy off the Manager field on a user profile.  For each of those direct reports, you need to ensure the manager is listed as such on their Profiles.